# Spring-Data-Rest with Dynamic Automatic Repository

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

Spring-Data-Rest allow us to publish automatiquely all declared Repositories,

suppose we have a DataBase of 500 entites, and we want to have the same result but without creating manualy a Repository for every entity,

how to do that?

Comment: Since the repository interface is very simple, you can generate it once for every entity and use it. If you eventually do this, it would be good to hear about how it performs.

Answer (score 0):

The repositories are a core part of how spring-data-rest works, so I don't think there is a way around creating repositories. Some databases support a direct REST API of their schema, you may want to look there.